# How to connect a Hive Database on Google Cloud Dataproc to Tableau Online, does Tableau Bridge helps in live connection?

Tags: hive, tableau-api, google-cloud-dataproc, liveconnect

How to connect a Hive Database on Google Cloud Dataproc to Tableau Online as a data source?
Does the Tableau Bridge helps in this to have live connection between Dataproc to Tableau Online?